# How to arrange data according status=True in django

Tags: python, django, django-views

I want to display card first which have status=True, so how can i arrange it by status in my `views.py` or in `template`

this is my `views.py`:

```
def myItem(request):
    context = {}
    if Item.objects.filter(status=True).exists():
        context['data'] = Item.objects.all()#here i am taking all data but i want to arrange it so that which data have status=True will come first.
    else:
        context['data'] = Item.objects.all()
        context['data_false'] = True
    return render(request,'frontend/myeoffice.html',context)
```

this is in my `Template`:

```
                    {% for i in data %}
                    {% if i.status %}
                    <div class="col-xl-4">
                        <div class="card shadow-sm p-4">
                            <div class="card-header p-0 text-center">
                                <h2 class="title">{{i.name}}</h2>
                            </div>
                            <div class="content text-break p-2">
                                <p class="copy">{{i.description|truncatechars:100}}</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="card-footer text-left p-0">
                                <button class="btn btn-primary m-3">View</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    {% else %}
                    <div class="col-xl-4">
                        <div class="card shadow-sm p-4" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".bd-example-modal-lg" style="background: #ccc;">
                            <div class="card-header p-0 text-center">
                                <h2 class="title">{{i.name}}</h2>
                            </div>
                            <div class="content text-break p-2">
                                <p class="copy">{{i.description|truncatechars:100}}</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="card-footer text-left p-0">
                                <button class="btn btn-primary disabled m-3" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".bd-example-modal-lg">
                                    View
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    {% endif %}
                    {% endfor %}
```

**NOTE** : I want data which have both status=False and status=True but order should be True first and False last

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can arrange the results via the order function:

```
def myItem(request):
    context = Item.objects.all().order_by('-status')
    return render(request,'frontend/myeoffice.html',context)
```

The `-` in `-status` is used to reverse order.

Answer (score 1):

You want to do this with the query to get the first one out of the result where status is True.

```
context['data'] = Item.objects.filter(status=True).first()
```

This will give you the first result with this status. Or if you want all results and order it by the status then do this:

```
context['data'] = Item.objects.all().order_by('-status')
```